# Query for field being null or a specific type

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to write a query to match a field that may have a type of `'null'` or `'objectid'` using [the `$type` operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/query/type/). When I query for just one particular type, it works:

```
> db.collections.post.findOne({$or: [{x: {$type: 'null'}}]}).then(console.log)
Promise { <pending> }
> { _id: 584f573f931f2b0bf4e3d339,
  date: Mon Dec 12 2016 21:04:47 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time),
  title: 'hgfgh',
  text: 'dhffgh',
  userId: 584f573a931f2b0bf4e3d338,
  x: null }
```

When I write a query that would also match `x` being `objectid`, I get nothing back:

```
> db.collections.post.findOne({$or: [{x: {$type: 'null'}}, {x: {$type: 'objectid'}}]}).then(console.log)
Promise { <pending> }
```

I’m using node-mongodb-native-2.2.

How do I write a query (I’m hoping to write this for a validator) that matches if a field is either `null` or an `ObjectId`?

Comment: can you try {$or: [{x: {$type: 'null'}}, {x: {$type: 'objectId'}}]} with capital I in object id ?

Comment: That was it. This makes me feel stupid xD. Though I really want to blame mongo’s query thing for not treating this like an error and raising an exception :-p.

Answer (score 0):

The approach I was using is apparently correct, just I mispelled `'objectId'` (see [“Available Types”](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/query/type/#document-type-available-types)) as `'objectid'`. Spelling the type name correctly caused mongodb to decide to interpret the query as a query instead of as a field match.

My theory of what happened to me was that mongodb gave up trying to coerce my query as a “query” and instead treated it like object key matching. I’m not sure how to go about avoiding this or if there’s a way to make mongodb raise an error when it can’t interpret a `$type` instead of silently changing how it interprets the query.

EDIT: Ah, I also figured out that mongodb *was* trying to tell me that my syntax was bad. I just didn’t put in a `.catch()` on my `Promise`. Oops…